# Can Elevation Layers in WCS be Combined?

Tags: geoserver, elevation, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wcs, terraexplorer

Some weeks ago, I began an effort at my company that required me to delve into the world of GIS. I've learned a lot since then, but there is one thing I'm not entirely clear on: is there is a way to combine elevation data served over WCS; more specifically, is there a way to do so in GeoServer?

**Here is a little background on the use case:**

We have piece of software we created that civil engineers use for work sites that allows them to carry out various calculations. We also have a web app that has a 3D Globe (ArcGIS), and another desktop app (Terra Explorer). The idea is that we extract imagery and elevation data from our software, create WMS and WCS layers from it in GeoServer, then load said layers up in those other globe apps. If there is a work site at some address in Colorado, for instance, and they zoom into that spot, they should just see the elevation and imagery there without having to search for any records or take any action.

I have figured out a way to do this with imagery in a way that isn't too taxing with regards to performance. When I extract imagery data, I create a WMS layer, add that layer to a layer group in GeoServer; then, I use GeoWebCache to serve up that layer group over WMTS.

**Here is my assumption about WCS as it relates to this:**

Given that GeoServer cannot create layer groups from WCS layers, and that each WCS layer is created from one input data source, and therefore one extract of our software, these WCS layers cannot be combined directly. Instead, we'd have to call `GetCapabilites` at the beginning of time, then call `DescribeCoverage` on every layer we found in the capabilites documents, populate some data structure with the extents of these layers, then use some algorithm to know that for the current map extent we have existing coverages for which we need to call `GetCoverage`. Absent of this, we would be loading elevation data for Africa, even though we're looking at China, for instance; which would be taxing.

**My general assumption about how WCS is normally consumed for elevation:**

It seems to me that the WCS services you find in the wild cover large areas: entire states, countries, continents. Whereas we might have several sites in one relatively small area like a single city. Given this, it makes our need for WCS a little more complicated.

**My questions:**

One: are my assumptions even correct in the first place?

Two: is there another way to go about this? I'm not asking for "better"  way of course, since that's subjective; but rather some alternative approaches.

Note: Terra Explorer only seems to understand elevation from WCS, which at least partially why I'm going down this road; and, there could be hundreds of these extracts, with a dozen or two happening in a given day.

**Source Data:**

Just so you know, the extracted elevation data is in GeoTiff format, and I'm not modifying it in any way with GDAL at this time. I'm trying to get a dynamic approach to loading elevation working first, then I'll start looking into optimization, overviews etc.

Comment: Use Image Mosaic. There can be gaps between the images.

Comment: Can you serve an image mosaic over WCS? Also, what about the case where there are new data extracts? Would you have to create a new mosaic each time and re-create the layer? I also seem to remember when testing with the GeoServer web interface that geotiffs didn't show up in the file explorer when trying to create and image mosaic store.

Comment: I took another look and the problem I had creating image mosaics from the geotiffs before is some other problem, likely Java related. Still, probably not the best solution, since I'd have to create a new mosaic and re-create the layer (we need a persistent url) every time we did an extract.

Comment: It is best to store the mosaic into database https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html.

Comment: How would that help with multiple extracts? Can you modify an existing store when data is added during the extraction?

Comment: It should be possible to update the index with new image footprints. This might be another option https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/imagemosaic.html

Comment: Those are both pretty good ides. I'm going to give them both a shot and see how it works out. I think it would be ok to turn your comments into one answer; provided you can elaborate on my WCS assumptions, it would be a complete answer that at least deserves an up-vote. I would of course accept it if it ends up working.

Comment: You can also write an answer yourself if you can make it to work. I can't do proper testing at the moment.